# Rails has_many :through with different column name in association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have two different models: `User` and `Project`. The `User` model has three types of users - owners, contractors and clients. I want to assign multiple contractors to one project. I am trying this with a `has_many :through` association, like so:

```
Class User
   has_many :assignments
   has_many :projects, :through => :assignments 

Class Project
   has_many :assignments
   has_many :contractors, :through => :assignments

Class Assignment
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :project
```

My issue is in using `contractor_id` in the `assignments` table instead of `user_id`.

In my `assignments` table I currently have columns `contractor_id` and `project_id`. Everything seems to work if I use `user_id` instead, but that will cause things to be pretty messy later on in my views.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use the [`:foreign_key`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) option in `Assignment`, e.g.:

```
class Assignment
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :contractor_id
  belongs_to :project
```

Comment: This definitely works the one way, now I just need to get the user model to recognize the `contractor_id` instead of `user_id` when I call `@user.projects`

Comment: got it. User model needed :foreign_key => :contractor_id on has_many :assignments